# Spring cloud gateway refusing query parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I am starting to set up a Spring Cloud Gateway and it works fine without query parameters in the uri. But I need some parameters and they are not fixed, I do not use them to select the routing, I just need them to be sent along with the uri, without any change.

For instance, the url:

http://localhost:8080/dev/selectconfig/v1/ABCDE

works but with the query parameters, it doesn't:

http://localhost:8080/dev/selectconfig/v1/ABCDE?config={"HEIGHT":22, "WIDTH": 30}

I receive 400 Bad request. I would like to redirect to the url:

[https://somehosthere.com/dev/selectconfig/v1/ABCDE?config={"HEIGHT":22](https://somehosthere.com/dev/selectconfig/v1/ABCDE?config=%7B%22HEIGHT%22:22), "WIDTH": 30}

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: route1
        uri: https://somehosthere.com/
        predicates:
        - Path=/dev/selectconfig/**
        filters:
        - AddRequestHeader=SOMEKEY, ${SOMEKEY}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>gw</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gw</name>
    <description>Gateway application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <io.jsonwebtoken.version>0.11.5</io.jsonwebtoken.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${io.jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${io.jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-orgjson</artifactId>
            <version>${io.jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    

</project>
```

Comment: curly braces are unsafe characters according to RFC 1738. Try encoding such characters before making the request.

Comment: This works, but I will receive requests from a customer with the brackets and I don't know if they will to change their requests format.

Comment: Incoming requests are now encoded and gateway is working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: route1
        uri: https://somehosthere.com/
        predicates:
        - Path=/dev/selectconfig/**
        - Query=config
        filters:
        - AddRequestHeader=SOMEKEY, ${SOMEKEY}
```

Please note `Query` predicate. You can add regex in case you want more control over query parameter values. Please refer [this](https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-cloud-docs/spring-cloud-gateway/gateway-request-predicates-factories/the-query-route-predicate-factory.html) link for more details

Comment: This works if I use  a value, but fails with the brackets.

Comment: @wilfredoronsini Is it possible to share minimum reproducible example? Probably you need to create regex which matches your query parameter value and use it